# Hyperlink of PDF files in QGIS2WEB

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have attached some pdf files in some features by using QGIS 3.8. 
After exporting the .qgs to webmap I am not able to access the hyperlink of the pdf files. It is shown there just as a text.

PS" I tried to use relative path and to put a subfolder within the webmap folder, but it is the same situation.

Is anyone who has experienced something similar?

Answer (score 2):

qgis2web won't automatically export the PDFs themselves. It tries to turn anything appropriate into a clickable hyperlink. So, if you have a field with a relative path to a folder within your export folder, and then copy the PDFs there, it should work. That does sound exactly like what you have tried, though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Tom. I did it, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Best thing to do would be to open an issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues. You'll be able to upload some of your files there, and we can try to figure out what is going wrong. The main extra detail we need is: in what specific way does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

It worked by adding : "< a target="_blank" href="./Hyperdokumente/Bayern/Kolbermoor/Grundbuchauszug/Grundbuch_Nr_10786.pdf">Open pdf " in an attribute table field.